# Font familyname programmatically in iphone

Tags: iphone, fonts

How to get all system font familymane by programmatically  in iPhone app
i want to display  it so user can choose it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
NSArray *fontNames;
NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
{
    NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
    fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                 [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
                  [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
    for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
    {
        NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
    }
    [fontNames release];
}
[familyNames release];
```

by using this code you can get Font Name and its familyname

Comment: Your solution is good but there's no benefit to allocating memory for familyNames. NSArray *familyNames = [UIFont familyNames]; would be fine. Same deal for fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                 [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
                  [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 NSLog("%@",[UIFont familyNames]);
```